# Aligning email body to match Pandas alignment

Tags: python

Been trying to get the email body to look like the Pandas output in the console but failed at every attempt so far. This is my latest attempt. Any help is appreciated.

Console Output:
[image]

Email Body Output:

[image]

My Code:

```
path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/PYTHON'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'data_*.csv'))

df_merged = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,all_files),ignore_index=True)
df_merged.to_csv('merged.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
email_body = df_merged.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'right'})

email_body = pd.read_csv('merged.csv')
print(email_body)
```

Comment: The dataframe you create with `email_body = pd.read_csv('merged.csv')` is distinct from `df_merged` so has no custom style properties.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The Pandas output seems to use a fixed-width font whereas the malformed example seems to use a variable-width one.

Comment: @tripleee How can I get around that? When I take out one of the columns, which I can and should, then it looks fine. It'd be nice to know for future referemce.

Comment: Jurt change the font in whatever it is you are using to look at the text. Monospace fonts often have names with "fixed" or "mono" in them, though some are just conventional, like Courier.